# Convert a list of dates into a string of date ranges

Tags: java, algorithm, datetime, data-structures, compression

I have a list of datetimes (technically, Joda LocalDateTime objects) in Java. I would like to print out a condensed form of the list, collapsing any date ranges. Something like the following list:

```
2013-11-24
2013-11-25
2013-11-26

2013-11-28
2013-11-29
2013-11-30


2013-12-03

2013-12-05
2013-12-06
2013-12-07
2013-12-08
2013-12-09
2013-12-10
2013-12-11
```

would print the following output:

```
2013-11-24->2013-11-26, 2013-11-28->2013-11-30, 2013-12-03, 2013-12-05->2013-12-11
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this than manually iterating over the list, comparing the next value, and constructing strings?

Comment: Without iterating, comparing and constructing strings, probably not. But with java 8 you can give a shot at streams, to make something compact.

Comment: This is support for a Java 7 application, so unfortunately that's not much help for us

Comment: can we expect the date values input to be sorted already?

Comment: Without iterating, comparing and constructing strings - Yes. Manually by looking with eyes and putting down on paper

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a class for this. Create an object of this class and check the next Date with `isFollowing()`. If it's true set the end date to the checked date (`setEnd(dateToCheck)`). If not, create a new DateRange object. It is required that your values are sorted before.

```
public class DateRange {

  private Date mStart;
  private Date mEnd;

  public DateRange(Date start) {
    mStart = start;
    mEnd = start;
  }

  public DateRange(Date start, Date end) {
    mStart = start;
    mEnd = end;
  }

  public boolean isInside() {
    // create your code
  }

  public boolean isFollowing(Date dateToCheck) {
    // create your code
    // check if dateToCheckis after start and end date
    // and the difference between end and dateToCheckis must be one day
  }

  public Date getStart() {
    return mStart;
  }

  public Date getEnd() {
    return mEnd;
  }

  public void setStart(Date start) {
    mStart = start;
  }

  public void setEnd(Date end) {
    mEnd = end;
  }
}
```